# Trouble with finding substrings with shell script

Tags: shell, substring

I have a file formatted something like this:

```
./07/00-post.log:Referer: http://domain1.com/example/launch.jsp?BANKID=123&SOMEPARAM=123&...
./07/00-post.log:Referer: http://domain2.com/example/launch.jsp?PARAM=313&BANKID=13&...
...
...
./07/00-post.log:Referer: http://domainN.com/example/launch.jsp?BANKID=3213
```

Need to find and extract followed substrings for each line into separate file using shell script:

1. Domain names between "http://" and "/" (domain1.com, domain2.com, ...)
2. BANKID's for that domains (can be at different positions)

so i can have pairs of domains and ids at output.

I think [cut](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/CUT/) won't work here. What utils can i use?

Comment: Look at awk and sed, these will meet your needs fine. There are lots of examples on the net and the google search will be very quick.  Also it will make an excellent addition to your tool set as a developer.   sed's regular expressions will handle this easily.

Answer (score 1):

As the text is noYou can use `grep` for this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=http://)[^/]*|(?<=BANKID=)\d*' file
domain1.com
123
domain2.com
13
domainN.com
3213
```

Which in fact is joining to different `grep` expressions:

Get the numbers after `BANKID=`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=BANKID=)\d*' file
123
13
3213
```

and get the domain after `http://` and up to next `/`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=http://)[^/]*' file
domain1.com
domain2.com
domainN.com
```

---

Note that `cut` is a tool to be used when the text format is homogeneous. It can work for the domains part:

```
$ cut -d/ -f5 file
domain1.com
domain2.com
domainN.com
```

But in general, it is a better job for `grep` or `sed` as per the `BANKID` requirement.

Comment: Nice, I like it, though he could use egrep (true but just joking the answer is correct)